# React hook form and MUI autocomplete wont register

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm trying to integrate MUI Autocomplete component with react-hook-form.

This is the code I currently have :

```
const { usersList } = useContext(BaseContext);
const { handleSubmit, control, register, reset } = useForm({
        defaultValues: {
            users: usersList.map((user) => user.id),
        },
    });
```

The `usersList` variable is correctly populated from the beginning since the component won't render unless it exists.

Then I call :

```
<form
  onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
  className="d-flex justify-content-start flex-wrap filters-content"
>
<div id={"content-users"}>
                <ThemeProvider theme={themeAutocomplete}>
                    <Autocomplete
                        limitTags={3}
                        multiple
                        id="size-small-outlined"
                        size="small"
                        options={usersList}
                        defaultValue={usersList}
                        className={"autocomplete m-1"}
                        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.fullName}
                        filterSelectedOptions
                        renderInput={(params) => (
                            <Controller
                                name="users"
                                control={control}
                                render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
                                    <TextField
                                        onChange={onChange}
                                        value={value}
                                        {...params}
                                        label={"Utilisateurs"}
                                    />
                                )}
                            />
                        )}
                    />
                </ThemeProvider>
            </div>
</form
```

Now, when I log my data on on submit, I get the preselected user, which is good. But when I delete on user from the autocomplete box, it won't be deleted in handleSubmit's data.
I tried many things such as :

```
                    <Autocomplete
                        limitTags={3}
                        multiple
                        id="size-small-outlined"
                        size="small"
                        options={usersList()}
                        defaultValue={usersList()}
                        className={"autocomplete m-1"}
                        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.fullName}
                        filterSelectedOptions
                        renderInput={(params) => (
                            <Controller
                                name="users"
                                control={control}
                                render={({ field }) => (
                                    <TextField
                                        {...field}
                                        {...params}
                                        label={"Utilisateurs"}
                                    />
                                )}
                            />
                        )}
                    />
```

or

```
                    <Controller
                        name="users"
                        control={control}
                        render={({ field }) => (
                            <Autocomplete
                                limitTags={3}
                                multiple
                                id="size-small-outlined"
                                size="small"
                                options={usersList()}
                                defaultValue={usersList()}
                                className={"autocomplete m-1"}
                                getOptionLabel={(option) => option.fullName}
                                filterSelectedOptions
                                renderInput={(params) => (
                                    <TextField
                                        {...field}
                                        {...params}
                                        label={"Utilisateurs"}
                                    />
                                )}
                            />
                        )}
                    />
```

or

```
                            <Autocomplete
                                limitTags={3}
                                multiple
                                id="size-small-outlined"
                                size="small"
                                options={usersList()}
                                defaultValue={usersList()}
                                className={"autocomplete m-1"}
                                getOptionLabel={(option) => option.fullName}
                                filterSelectedOptions
                                renderInput={(params) => (
                                    <TextField
                                        inputProps={register('users')}
                                        {...params}
                                        label={"Utilisateurs"}
                                    />
                                )}
                            />
```

But can't figure out why it wont change when i modify the selection ....